How to add a collection from a Blend file via add-on code?
This is my current code:
import bpy

class AppendCollectionOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.append_collection_operator"
    bl_label = "Append Collection from .blend"
    
    filepath: bpy.props.StringProperty(subtype='FILE_PATH')
    collection_name: bpy.props.StringProperty()

    def execute(self, context):
        # Append .blend file
        with bpy.data.libraries.load(self.filepath) as (data_from, data_to):
            data_to.collections = [name for name in data_from.collections]

        # Link the collection to the scene
        for coll in data_to.collections:
            bpy.context.collection.children.link(coll)

        return {'FINISHED'}

class AppendCollectionPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Append Collection Panel"
    bl_idname = "PT_AppendCollectionPanel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'Tools'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        # Filepath input
        layout.prop(context.scene, "blend_filepath", text="Blend File Path")

        # Collection dropdown
        layout.prop_search(context.scene, "collection_name", bpy.data, "collections", text="Collection")

        # Append button
        layout.operator("object.append_collection_operator", text="Append Collection")

    def update_collections(self, context):
        # Update collections list based on blend_filepath
        filepath = context.scene.blend_filepath
        with bpy.data.libraries.load(filepath) as (data_from, data_to):
            data_to.collections = [name for name in data_from.collections]

        self.layout.prop(context.scene, "collection_name", text="Collection")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(AppendCollectionOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(AppendCollectionPanel)

    bpy.types.Scene.blend_filepath = bpy.props.StringProperty(subtype='FILE_PATH', update=AppendCollectionPanel.update_collections)
    bpy.types.Scene.collection_name = bpy.props.StringProperty()

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(AppendCollectionOperator)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(AppendCollectionPanel)

    del bpy.types.Scene.blend_filepath
    del bpy.types.Scene.collection_name

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()


You really should show the error message you’re getting, not just the code you’re using. Also, why make an add-on for this? Why not just use Blender’s asset system, or the built in collection importer?

Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "\Text", line 12, in execute
OSError: load:  failed to open blend file

Blender's asset system is too large or the collection imports are too repetitive.

The asset system is too… “large”? How so? Do you have too many assets? To effectively scroll through them?

Go ahead and edit the error into the question. After pasting, select it and use the code block formatting button to make it show up nicely.

Correct! Imagine that if I have 100 characters. Then opening the folder and starting "Append" with default operations will take a lot of time. My job requires making 5 short videos in a day.

This addon will be of great help to students. Just reducing operations by 1 second saves 100 seconds of work with 100 characters.

This should throw an error when you setup a file path, doesn't it ? self.layout.prop(context.scene, "collection_name", text="Collection")

You know the asset browser has a search engine, right?

Using "Asset System" to "append collection" with "Armature" will create a "collection instance". I can't adjust "Pose" with "collection instance". So how can "Append" be like the command "bpy.ops.wm.append()"
